# File size changes after downloading from online server to hard disk. What causes this?

Tags: ftp

I need clear explanation about this subject. From my online server I downloaded a file (.htaccess) for this I use Filezilla as FTP client.
After downloading the file I noticed that the filesize had increased from 482 to 496 kb. What causes this change in filesize?

I did the following research in google:
“filesize changes after download from server site:stackoverflow.com”
“filesize changes after download from server site:serverfault.com”

The reason I ask this here is because my problem might be specific regarding Filezilla , my serverprovider and my desktop harddisk settings.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a plaintext file and I am going to assume you’ve downloaded this from aLinux host to a Windows host.

The extra bytes will be taken up by the LF (Line Feed) to CR/LF (Carriage Return/Line Feed)conversion that takes place when you perform an ASCII transfer (not binary) over FTP.

After you’ve edited the file and transferred it back, it’ll be converted to LF from CR/LF.

This is done because text files on Linux use a single LF character as the line ending and Windows uses a CR/LF combination as the line ending.  FTP does the conversion so that DOS and Windows text editors are able to edit these files without corrupting them.

Comment: Note that most Windows text editors these days handle text files with just LF (e.g. Notepad++ or even the ancient WordPad) perfectly fine. AFAIK only the original Windows Notepad chokes on such files, but there are probably other obscure editors out there that also can't handle them.

Comment: They do but they have no way of knowing “how” the file got onto the local disk.  This situation would only occur if the FTP client willingly transferred a text file in Binary mode and most will not, by default.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Windows **10** notepad does handle bare LF, at last. _And_ it lets you do UTF8 without BOM, which previous versions couldn't. Greg: _FTP_ clients will usually do Text, but SFTP and SCP access is now common and only does binary, as does HTTP[S] e.g. rightclick/saveas in a browser.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 There’s also FTPS that supports text/binary.  I agree that there are less and less uses of text mode transfer as pretty much every text editor can recognise specific line endings.